# Filling memory, what's happening

Tags: powershell

The simple statement, `1..1GB`, fills memory and appears to be hung on a 32 GiB system. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> does nothing. What is happening inside the interpreter? If it is allowed to run long enough, will the correct result be produced?

```
PS C:\> (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).TotalPhysicalMemory / 1MB
32629.1484375
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.3.4
PS C:\> 1..1GB
```

Comment: You're creating an array of 1GB elements and output it to the console....

Comment: When you exceed the actual memory Virtual memory is used which is temp space on a hard drive.  Depending on type of hard drive on system and the size of virtual memory on your machine would determine what is happening.

Comment: Further reading… ```..``` is called the “Range operator” - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3#range-operator- and ```GB``` is the “gigabyte multiplier” - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-7.3#integer-literals

Comment: 5.1 doesn't even allow it.  `foreach ($i in 1..1gb)` will run fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`..`**, PowerShell's **[range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-)**:

- ***lazily enumerates* the values** between the (inclusive) range endpoints (in the case at at hand, `1`, `2`, `3`, ..., `1073741824`)
- **when the results are *captured***, such as by enclosing the range operation in `(...)`, assigning it to a variable, or making it participate in a larger expression, **PowerShell creates an `[object[]]` array** for the enumerated values (verify with `(1..10).GetType()`).

Given the sheer number of values, **enumerating `1GB` == `1,073,741,824` (1+ billion)<sup>[1]</sup> values with `1..1GB` is *very slow* - but *does* eventually return (unless you run out of memory)** in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), whereas in *Windows PowerShell* it fails right away; as [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) notes:

- > in Windows PowerShell (64-bit), `$array = 1..1GB` fails with an `OutOfMemoryException` (`Array dimensions exceeded supported range.`). The actual limit is even lower (`$array = 1..300MB` still fails, while `$array = 1..200MB` succeeds).
- The reason is that .NET Framework, the legacy, Windows-only runtime underlying Windows PowerShell, has a limit not just on the *element count* of an array (close to 2 GB, i.e. 2+ billion elements per dimension), but also on the *overall byte size* of an array dimension, which is 2 GB as well.

  - Therefore, given that each element of an `[object[]]` array is the size of a pointer (reference) and given that in 64-bit processes each pointer requires 8 bytes (verify with `[IntPtr]::Size`), the actual limit is near `2GB / 8`; `256MB - 8`, to be precise. That is, `$array = 1..(256MB - 8)` works, but anything with more values fails.
  - However, the limit is *higher* - and the same for both PowerShell editions - if you *stream* the range operation instead of causing an *array* to be created - see next section.
- .NET (Core), the modern, cross-platform runtime underlying PowerShell (Core) 7+, doesn't have this byte-size limit any longer, but is still limited in terms of *element count* to near 2 GB, i.e. 2+ billion elements; zett42 has worked out the exact limit: `2GB - 57`, i.e. `2,147,483,591` elements per dimension (`[int]::MaxValue - 56`; verify with `[object[]]::new(2GB - 57).Count` - anything higher, such as `- 56`, fails with `Array dimensions exceeded supported range.`)

  - As an aside: In *multidimensional* arrays an additional constraint is that the *combined* element count, across all dimensions, must not exceed 4+ billion elements (`4,294,967,182` == `4GB - 114`, to be precise). Use of such arrays is rare in PowerShell, however, and the more commonly used *jagged* arrays (arrays whose elements are other arrays) are *not* subject to this limit.

---

Note that **if you use a range operation as *pipeline input*,** *without enclosing it in `(...)`*, the lazy enumeration behavior comes apparent - ***no array is created*, and the enumerated values are *streamed***:

```bash
# Prints 1, 2, ..., 10 virtually *instantly*, because the values
# are *streamed* to Select-Object
1..1GB | Select-Object -First 10
```

If you use this form:

- You are ***not* subject to *array* size constraints**, so that the above works in *Windows PowerShell* too.
- All that matters when streaming is that the **range endpoints must be / fit into `[int]` (`System.Int32`)**, which makes the ***implied* limit on the element count** the number of integers `[int]` can represent, which is **`[UInt32]::MaxValue + 1`**,<sup>[2]</sup> which is `4,294,967,296` (`4GB`).

Note that **`..` is *unusual*** among PowerShell operators, in that it **combines non-pipeline and pipeline behaviors**: *in isolation* - when you neither capture it nor send it to another command - it is *implicitly* captured in an `[object[]]` array, and only after its creation does the resulting array's to-host (to-console) output start; that is, **streaming does *not* happen unless you use the operation as input to an *explicit* pipeline**.

- Compare the output behavior of `1..50MB` to that of `1..50MB | Write-Output`: the former creates a noticeable delay before output starts, due to a (large) array getting created first, whereas the latter *streams* its values and therefore starts producing output instantly.

The ***situationally* streaming behavior *also* surfaces in the context of the [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) and [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statements**:

- The following commands work in *both* PowerShell editions, due to `..` exhibiting *streaming* behavior there too:

  ```bash
  # Outputs 1, received in a *streaming* fashion, then exits.
  # Subject only to the 2GB-1 limit.
  foreach ($i in 1..(2GB-1)) { $i; break }      

  # Ditto
  switch (1..(2GB-1)) { default { $_; break } }
  ```

---

<sup>[1] As [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton) points out, the `GB` suffix is the *(binary) gigabtye multiplier* (amounting to a factor of `[Math]::Pow(2, 30)` == `1,073,741,824`), one of several [binary multipliers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals#integer-literals) that PowerShell supports in number *literals*.</sup>

<sup>[2] Another way of calculating this limit: `-[int]::MinValue + [int]::MaxValue + 1` (the `+ 1` is for `0`).</sup>

Comment: As an aside, that `switch` "loop" without a `break` unexpectedly runs about twice as fast as a `foreach` loop on my machine (PS 7.34): `Measure-Command { $i = switch (1..10MB) { default { $_ } } } | % TotalSeconds` vs. `Measure-Command { $i = foreach ($j in 1..10MB) { $j } } | % TotalSeconds`.

Comment: @zett42, I wonder if this was an artifact of runtime conditions and doing only a single run each: When I average 15 runs, I see no difference in performance.
I usually use my `Time-Command` function, from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27), which averages 15 runs by default
and also runs the garbage collector beforehand.